# R: Use geom_smooth on a forecast time serie

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, smoothing

I've got a problem with a time serie I'm making with forecast. I was asked to add a line into the layer `trend` that should give the linear evolution. To be clearer: I have to reproduce the `geom_smooth` comportement inside this table. Here a minimal reproducible example:

```
require(forecast)
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

nottem.stl = stl(nottem, s.window="periodic")
autoplot(nottem.stl)

dmn <- list(month.abb, unique(floor(time(nottem))))
nottem.df <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(nottem, 12, dimnames = dmn)))
nottem.df$mean <- rowMeans(nottem.df, na.rm = TRUE)
nottem.df <- tibble::rownames_to_column(nottem.df)
nottem.df$rowname <- as.numeric(nottem.df$rowname)

ggplot(data=nottem.df, aes(x=rowname, y=mean))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', color="blue")
```

My goal would be to have a somewhat approachable result for the autoplot grid `trend` as the `ggplot` example above. The reason I need that is that the trend on my data set are not really linear and it is hard to guess if there is an general increase or decrease along the years.

Any help would be welcome. If the question is unclear/uncomplete, let me know in the comments and I'll edit it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: autoplot(nottem.stl) +
  geom_smooth() ?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It works in some way, because it did the job on the grid `trend`, but sadly above the other grids too (`data`, `seasonal`, ...). How could I avoid that?

Comment: I suppose you could always plot your series one at a time, apply `geom_smooth` to the trend series only and then stitch them back together using grid. `autoplot(nottem.stl$time.series[,"trend"], facets = TRUE) + geom_smooth(method = "lm")` should give you one of the panes.

Comment: If you submit that as an answer and add what code you mean with "using grid", because I'm not sure what you mean, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Just glad to help, the problem is a bit too specific for the site tough (at least for my tastes). grid, in short, is a package for handling graphics. An example of how it may be used for  plotting any nummer of ggplot graphs side by side can be found here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/